# How can 2 different node.js process can send event between each others?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have 2 different node.js process that run at the same place. I want, from process A, send an event to process B.

I tried EventEmitter, but it looks like my thought about using the same notifier.js file (see below) is not something that could work. Am I right? I am asking that because it does not look like my process B is receiving the message emitted by process A.

notifier.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
var notifier = new EventEmitter()
const notifierExport = {
   notifier
}
module.exports = notifierExport
```

in process A

```
const notifier = require('notifier').notifier

notifier.emit('myEvent', "...")
```

in process B

```
const notifier = require('notifier').notifier

notifier.on('myEvent', () => {
   ...
})
```

Comment: How are these two node.js processes started?  Are they started completely separately?  Or can you start one as a child_process of the other?  With a child_process, interprocess messaging is built into node.js.  If you can't do a child_process, then you could just give one of your node.js processes a simple little Express web server on a known port and the other could send it http requests.

Comment: BTW, you are correct that an `EventEmitter` by itself will not work for this.  That's just good within one node.js process.  It doesn't know anything about other processes.

Comment: @jfriend00, systemd is starting them. So based on your comment, the child_process could be an idea that I will investigate. Thanks